# Intuition of the concepts behind Ergodic Theory

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, ergodic-theory, topological-dynamics

As a graduate math and physics student, I am introducing myself to the study of Ergodic Theory, reading Introduction to the Modern Theory of Dynamical Systems, by Katok and Hasselblatt. I understand the mathematical definitions but it seems to me that there is no “intuition” behind the concepts or motivation. My aim is to apply Ergodic Theory to Quantum-mechanical systems.
For example, I cannot “see” what is a topologically transitive or topologically mixing dynamical system, and I don’t know where I can get better explanations. Anyone can help me with this, explaining me the aim of such concepts I have mentioned or giving me some references? Thanks.

Comment: Curious, why do you want to apply this theory to QM?

Comment: @Kevin my aim is to study Shnirelman Theorem and Quantum Chaos :)